# what is the purpose of spring boot autowired annotation on a constructor?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

what is the purpose of @Autowired annotation on a constructor? What is the difference between non-annotated and annotated constructor? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't the doc clear on that? https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html

Comment: It is called constructor dependency injection please go through the below website for your clarification https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring

Answer (score 0):

Autowiring feature enables you to inject the object dependency implicitly.

Without autowiring you have to initiate the object like:

```
    public class SomeOperation() {

        private CarService carService;

        public SomeOperation() {

            carService = new CarServiceImpl();
        }
    }
```

But if you annotate with @Autowired you don't have to initiate the object. The framework will bring the class which implements the carService and initiate your object with it.

```
    public class SomeOperation() {

        private CarService carService;

        @Autowired
        public SomeOperation(CarService carService) {

            this.carService = carService;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between non-annotated and annotated
>   constructor?

In Spring 3 or below, the annotation on the constructor is mandatory to make Spring consider the constructor as the way to instantiate the bean and inject dependencies provided in parameters.
Spring 4 and above versions don't require the annotation to do that.
You just need to declare the constructor with any parameter to achieve that.
So in recent Spring versions, don't clutter the code with the annotation :

```
public Foo(Bar bar){
  this.bar = bar;
}
```